# Python - Extract Informations from Docx-File into Pandas Df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, docx, text-extraction

I have a Word-Document with the contents of an interview and want to store every question and answer in a Pandas dataframe.
The word-document looks like this:

[image: word doc]

So in the end I want a pandas dataframe like:

```
participant | Question_Number | question | answer | timestamps_difference
VP01        |       1         | SOME Q.. | SOME A.| 00:00:02
```

I firstly used the "textract"-Package to read in the docx-file. After reading the document in, all content is now stored in one string (but type of text is byte):

```
import textract
text = textract.process("Transkript VP01_test.docx")
text
text = text.decode("utf-8") #convert byte to string
```

[image]

> b'Lehrstuhl f\xc3\xbcr Kinder- und Jugendpsychiatrie\n\n\t\tund
> -psychotherapie\n\n\t\n\n\n\nInterview-Transkription\n\nVP: 01\t\t\t\t\t\t   Interview-Dauer:
> 00:05:55\t\n\n\n\nTranskriptionsregeln: Es wird w\xc3\xb6rtlich
> transkribiert, nicht lautsprachlich. Vorhandene Dialekte werden
> m\xc3\xb6glichst wortgenau ins Hochdeutsche \xc3\xbcbersetzt.
> Satzabbr\xc3\xbcche, Stottern und Wortdoppelungen werden ausgelassen.
> Die Interpunktion wird zugunsten der Lesbarkeit nachtr\xc3\xa4glich
> gesetzt.\n\nGespr\xc3\xa4chsteilnehmer: Interviewer (RB); Participant
> (VP01)\n\nInterview-Transkription:\n\n#00:00:00#: STARTING\n\nRB: SOME
> QUESTION HERE #00:00:14#\n\nVP01: SOME ANSWER HERE. #00:00:16#\n\nRB:
> SOME TEXT HERE #00:00:17#\n\nVP01: SOME ANSWER HERE. #00:00:40#
> \n\nRB: SOME QUESTION HERE #00:00:41#\n\nVP01: SOME ANSWER HERE

Comment: I recommend you copy and paste the byte output instead of the screenshot. It's always a bad idea to share text as a picture. Share the text itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import textract
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

input_string = textract.process("Transkript VP01_test.docx")

# Extract questions and timestamps using regular expression
pattern = r'(?P<Participant>RB|VP01):\s(?P<Question>.*?)\s#(?P<Timestamp>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})#'
matches = re.findall(pattern, input_string)

# Create a dictionary to store the extracted data
data_dict = {'Participant': [], 'Question': [], 'Timestamp': [], 'Answer': [], 'Time_Difference_in_Sec': []}

# Iterate through the matches and store the data in the dictionary
for i in range(len(matches)):
    participant = matches[i][0]
    question = matches[i][1]
    question_timestamp = datetime.strptime(matches[i][2], '%H:%M:%S')
    
    if i < len(matches) - 1:
        answer = matches[i+1][1]
        answer_timestamp = datetime.strptime(matches[i+1][2], '%H:%M:%S')
        time_difference = (answer_timestamp - question_timestamp).seconds
    else:
        answer = ''
        time_difference = ''
    
    data_dict['Participant'].append(participant)
    data_dict['Question'].append(question)
    data_dict['Timestamp'].append(matches[i][2])
    data_dict['Answer'].append(answer)
    data_dict['Time_Difference_in_Sec'].append(time_difference)

# Extract interview duration using regular expression
duration_pattern = r'Interview-Dauer:\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
duration_match = re.search(duration_pattern, input_string)
if duration_match:
    interview_duration = duration_match.group(1)
else:
    interview_duration = ''

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# Add interview duration as a column in the DataFrame
df['Interview Duration'] = interview_duration

# Display the DataFrame
df

  Participant            Question Timestamp              Answer  \
0          RB  SOME QUESTION HERE  00:00:14   SOME ANSWER HERE.   
1        VP01   SOME ANSWER HERE.  00:00:16      SOME TEXT HERE   
2          RB      SOME TEXT HERE  00:00:17   SOME ANSWER HERE.   
3        VP01   SOME ANSWER HERE.  00:00:40  SOME QUESTION HERE   
4          RB  SOME QUESTION HERE  00:00:41    SOME ANSWER HERE   

  Time_Difference_in_Sec Interview Duration  
0                      2           00:05:55  
1                      1           00:05:55  
2                     23           00:05:55  
3                      1           00:05:55  
4                      8           00:05:55
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your bytes to str by using the `byte.decode(self)` function or str constructor.

Then, if you need to find a pattern to separate the fluff from the data you want. Here, that pattern I see is the `#00:00:00#: STARTING` split by that and take the string at index 1 or use regex to match and replace `.*?thatstring` or something like that.

Next, if you can assure that every new line is a different speaker, you can split by `\n\n`, take the resulting list and iterate through. You can use a for loop similar to the following (I haven't tested it so revise before use)

```py
data = list()
buffer = 0
for i, line in enumerate(transcript):
    speaker, rest = line.split(":", 1)
    text, timestamp = rest[:-10], rest[-10:]
    # Only use this if you're sure the length of the timestamp will remain the same (10).
    # If not, you can use some regex to match or a custom reverse index function to find where to split.

    if i % 2 == 0: # Then you know it's the interviewer speaking (assuming only two speakers)
        buffer = [[text, timestamp]]
    else:
        buffer.append([text, timestamp, speaker])
        # Flush your buffer into the data list
        data.append(buffer)
```

Now that you have your data, you can do something things to map your list to the way you want.

You could easily:

- create a parsing function for your timestamps and map it with list comprehension.
- use enumerate and i+1 to map your index to the question number.
- combine the list pairs, in the specific order:

  - each_data[1][2]; answerer/participant
  - the question number
  - each_data[0][0]; question
  - each_data[1][0]; answer
  - each_data[1][1] - each_data[0][1]; time diff

At the end of mapping, your format `list[list[str, time], list[str, time, str]]` should become `list[list[str, int, str, str, timediff/int]]`

Then loading that to a dataframe is easy:

```py
columns = ["participant", "Question_Number", "question", "answer", "timestamps_difference"]
your_df = pd.DataFrame(mapped_data, columns=columns)
```

Here's documentation for the DataFrame constructor:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame

I did not test my code since I do not have your word doc so do a bit of testing before use.

Comment: What type do you expect for "transcript"? It doesn't work for me with type 'bytes' or type 'string'. Error: "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: @MaxlGemeinderat transcript would be a list of strings. enumerate would turn it to a list of tuples with an index and string as its elements